# Scroll to element on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to scroll to an element on another page.

I have contact details at the bottom of xyz page and a contact button on the about us page. Once the user clicks the contact button on the about us page i would like them to go to xyz page and then automatically scroll to contact details at bottom.

```
$("#contact-btn").click(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
                }, 1000);
            //});
        });
```

Comment: No need for the javascript in this context, either a link, `<a href="uri#anchor">link</a>` or `window.location` redirect with the anchor included. You could pass it as a querystring, then animate to the anchor on the subsequent page, if animation is important.

Comment: Or load the contact details with AJAX for the original page to display.

Answer (score 2):

### Sure you can...

Let's say you have a link on "index.htm": `<a href="contact.htm#bottom">Contact</a>`.

And on site "contact.htm" you have a tag: `<div id="bottom"></div>`.

**So if the browser loads the new site with hash "http://yoursite.com/contact.htm#bottom" it will "jump" to the bottom of the page automatically - but this will not look like a scroll event!**

If you want to have a nice scroll effect you must not have an anchor with id equals hash but read the hash with javascript `document.location.hash` analyze it and scroll like you are used to scroll if the user is on the same site the scroll event takes place.

best regards :)